# How to embed an Excel Workbook showing the inserted Task Pane Add-in on a web page?

Tags: embed, office-js, excel-addins

Context

- Excel Workbooks can be embedded on a Web Page ([see documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/share-it-embed-an-excel-workbook-on-your-web-page-or-blog-from-onedrive-804e1845-5662-487e-9b38-f96307144081?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us))
- Content Pane Add-ins are displayed in the Excel Workbook embed
  (iframe)
- Task Pane Add-ins are not displayed (because they are in their own
  iframe?)

How to embed an Excel Workbook showing the inserted Task Pane Add-in on a web page?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.